# Request header field authentication is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

**--It was a host error. Issue is solved--**

I am using express API.
I have enabled all cors through npm `cors` package.
like this `app.use(cors())`

It's working fine when I run it on localhost.
It was also working fine on the actual VPS (server), but suddenly today my API started giving me this error:-

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://apilink' from origin 'https://frontendlink' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authentication is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

It's still working fine on my localhost, but now giving above error on actual website.

Below are some of my code block

Thanks in advance

**My Axios Instance on frontend**

```js
import axios from "axios"

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    headers: {
        Authentication: `Bearer ${
            somewhere_token ?? null
        }`,
    },
})

export default axiosInstance
```

**SomeWhere in server.js before all routes**

```js
app.use(cors())
```

**I have also tried below solutions in server.js file but none is fixing my issue**

```js
// solution 1
app.options('*', cors());
// solution 2
app.use(cors({
    origin: "*",
    allowedHeaders: "*",
}))
```

Comment: let us know what client side receives from the request. thanks!

Comment: it receives the same error what i have shown in the very first code block

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can fix it by adding * everywhere, but please consider using a reverse proxy to make your request to backend proxy-passed from frontend host as the best practice. I know it's an additional learning curve, but for modern APIs that's probably must have as it allows much more than just solving CORS issue.

Good guide here https://blogs.perficient.com/2021/02/10/nginx-proxy-for-cors/